# How to create a generic Style resource for Windows Phone 8's TextBlock

Tags: windows-phone-8, styles, textblock

I've got some TextBlock in my wp8 app which have the same style: for example, they all need to be underlined, bold and something else..

Is there the possibility to centralize this common style without repeating all style's declarations for each TextBlock in my application?

Could you give me some working example?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In App.xaml resources you can define global styles for all pages. If you want to have the same style for all `TextBlock`, the style has to contain only `TargetType`, but not `x:Key`.

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>

        <!-- All TextBlock(s) -->
        <Style
            TargetType="TextBlock">

            <Setter
                Property="FontSize"
                Value="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeExtraLarge}" />

            <Setter
                Property="FontWeight"
                Value="Bold" />

            <!-- something else -->

        </Style>

    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for.. Maybe it's the basic but i've got plenty of time and you saved me!
Great!